# concurrent threads for a method of EJB

Tags: java, concurrency, ejb

I have a stateless EJB with method that process data. Usually method works 5..20 seconds

I need to have about 10 threads, that executes that method concurrently. So I made annotation for that method `@Schedule(second = "*", minute = "*", hour = "*")`
But container (Glassfish 4) launches only one thread for my method.

I tried to use annotation `@Asynchronous`, but it make no effect

What should I do?

Comment: Use 10 stateless session beans.

Answer (score 2):

Write a second class using the `@Schedule(second = "*", minute = "*", hour = "*")` to call your `@Asynchronous` EJB method - then, if the duration is as you said, it should start a new thread every second.

## Minimal Example

### Caller.java

```
public class Caller {

    @EJB
    AsyncEJB asyncEjb;       

    @Schedule(second = "*", minute = "*", hour = "*")
    public void call() {
        this.asyncEjb.call(); 
    }
}
```

### AsyncEJB.java

```
@Stateless
public class AsyncEJB {

    @Asynchronous
    public void call() {
        // Do long running stuff.
    }
}
```